# Gradle Sub Projects Builds Are Failed If Sub Projects Contains Same File Name In Same Package Structure

Tags: gradle, xtext, xtend

Here is my Project structure.

**Note:Project-B depends on Project-A Build**

[image]

I have following attributes in SamplePage.Java

**Project-A->SamplePage.Java**

```
public string name;
  public int age;
```

**Project-B->SamplePage.Java**

```
public string name;
```

I have a [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) class that will refer Project-B SamplePage.java class and it failed the build throwing `The method or field age is undefined for the type SamplePage.java.Execution failed for task ':Project-B:generateXtext'`.If i put `age` attribute to Project-B SamplePage.java it builds successfully.My question is that how can i over come that problem?Not sure if i did some mistake in build script file.

**Build.Gradle**

```
allprojects  {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'org.xtext.xtend'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

eclipse {
      project {
        natures 'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextNature'
        buildCommand 'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextBuilder'
      }
    } 

}

etc...
```